# How to read $\exists x \forall y \exists z((x + y)z = 1)$?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

> $$\exists x \forall y \exists z((x + y)z = 1)$$

How can I translate this expression to English? And is the statement true or false? (for numbers in $\Bbb R$).

$z=1$ is the part that confuses me.

Comment: It's not $z=1$, but $(x+y)z=1$.  Hint: the statement is false.

Comment: Think of it as: There is an $x$ such that for all $y$, the equation $(x+y)z=1$ has a solution in $z$.

Comment: Do you mean it says z multiplied with (x+y) should be 1?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It translates as:

There exists an $x$ such that whatever $y$ you choose you can find an $z$ such that $x+y$ multiplied by $z$ equals $1$.

It is false because no matter what value $x$ has, whenever $y=-x$, $x+y$ multiplied by $z$ is zero.

Comment: You can't for $y=0$.